# How to correctly update <select multiple ...> in React?

Tags: reactjs, select, jsx, dropdown, controlled-component

In a react app, you should control a `<select>`. It's real easy with a single select:

```
const ExampleSelect = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState()
  return (
    <select
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
    >
      <option value='foo'>Foo</option>
      <option value='bar'>Bar</option>
      <option value='baz'>Baz</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

But when you add the `multiple` prop to a `<select>` things get weird. Functions passed to `onChange` that iterate through the options and take actions based on which ones have `option.selected === true` only seem to work on desktop -- in Safari on iOS, a select with `multiple === true` seems impossible to control.

I feel like this is a really basic question, but I can't find anything on it. I'm not looking to install a whole library that comes with pre-styled components just to be able to select multiple options in a `<select>` inside a react app.

Here are a few onChange functions I've tried:

```
type Setter = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[] | undefined>>
type SelectChange = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>

export const handleMultiSelectChange = <S extends Function = Setter>(
  value: string[] | undefined, setter: S
) => (
    e: SelectChange
  ): void => {
    const v = e.currentTarget.value
    if (value && value.length > 0) {
      const index = value.indexOf(v)
      if (index >= 0) {
        const newValue = value.filter((opt) => opt !== v)
        setter(newValue)
      } else {
        setter([...value, v])
      }
    } else {
      setter([v])
    }
  }
```

```
type Setter = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string[] | undefined>>
type SelectChange = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>

export const handleChangeMultiple = <S extends Function = Setter>(
  value: string[] | undefined = [], setter: S
) => (
    event: SelectChange
  ): void => {
    const {options} = event.currentTarget
    for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      const option = options[i]
      if (option.selected) {
        alert(value.includes(option.value))
        if (value.includes(option.value)) {
          const index = value.indexOf(option.value)
          value.splice(index, 1)
        } else {
          value.push(option.value)
        }
      }
    }
    setter(value)
  }
```

(those ones are used like this:)

```
const ExampleSelect = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState()
  return (
    <select
      multiple
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChangeMultiple(value, setValue)}
    >
      <option value='foo'>Foo</option>
      <option value='bar'>Bar</option>
      <option value='baz'>Baz</option>
    </select>
  )
}
```

(though that's not working correctly for me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For select, `e.target` gives you `options` array and you can loop thru it get`selected` option. Use `map` to grab the actual values and store them in your state.

**select**

```js
   <select
        onChange={handleChangeNormalSelect}
        multiple
        value={val}
        options={options}
      >
        {options.map(item => {
          return <option value={item.value}>{item.label}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
```

**onChange**

```js
...
const [val, setVal] = useState([]);
...
const handleChangeNormalSelect = e => {
    const updatedOptions = [...e.target.options]
      .filter(option => option.selected)
      .map(x => x.value);
    console.log("updatedOptions", updatedOptions);
    setVal(updatedOptions);
  };
...
```

Working [code sample(html multi select) is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-select-issue-fix-7y9gn?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This code sample doesn't help... you're using the `react-select` library. I'm explicitly trying to use a plain `<select>` so I don't have to install a bunch of libraries that come with opinionated styling.

Comment: The html multi select also does not work. You can only select a single option in it at a time.

Comment: it works... hold control button (or command button if using mac) and click thru options to select multiple.... also i have removed react-select part of code from the codesandbox..

Comment: dang, sorry for that @gdh... when using a plain html select with `multiple === true`  outside of a react app, you don't need to hold cmd/shift to select multiple on a Mac. I clicked one option, it became selected, then I clicked another, and then the second became the only selected option. I see now that you're right, using cmd/shift does allow me to select multiple or a range of the presented options. Thanks!